# CursorHold event not working on nohlsearch

Tags: search

I added `set hlsearch` to highlight my searches which is helpful. And I can turn it off by using `:nohlsearch` or remapping that to a key. But when I tried to use it on `CursorHold` event, it doesn't work. Other commands work on `CursorHold` but not for `nohl` or `nohlsearch`.

CursorHold on my .vimrc:

```
"clear highlight search every 1sec
set updatetime=1000
autocmd CursorHold * exec "noh"
```

Comment: This is going to be tricky. According to `:h autocmd-searchpat` highlighting is restored after `autocmd` events. However I know that [vim-cool](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool) does something similar. I would look to that plugin for inspiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, that your `:exe "noh"` does not need exe, you could simply use `:noh`, since you do not need to dynamically build up a string as command.

As mentioned in the comment, this does not work, because of what is described at [`:help autocmd-searchpat`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-searchpat). 
However there are a couple of workarounds:

- Using [`feedkeys()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29)

`:autocmd CursorHold * :sil call feedkeys(":nohls\<cr>\<c-l>", 'tn')`
This will use feedkeys using the `t`and `n` flags which makes sure, Vim receives the input as if *the user typed it like that* and works around the problem mentioned at `:h autocmd-searchpat`

- Using CmdlindLeave autocommand

This is a relatively new autocommand, that was included with patch [8.0.1206](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1206) and can be used to automatically set `:nohls` after leaving the commandline as explained at [`:help 'incsearch'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27)
Note: This feature is only available since patch [8.0.1238](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1238)

Comment: Great thanks `feedkeys` work. I'm not new to linux, but I just started modifying my vimrc and not yet familiar with some differences like the use of `exe`